# Help needed in showing halobenzene resonance in LaTeX

Tags: chemfig

I am new to LaTeX, can someone please help me in showing the following using LaTeX, I can make the halobenzene rings, and I am comfortable with `\lewis`, I just want help in those arrows.

[image: Resonance Structure of Chlorobenzene]

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**: Here's how much I can do by myself, I would also like to know how can I decrease the size of the rings so that they can be fitted in a line. Thanks.

```
\begin{center}
 \chemfig{*6(-=-=(-\lewis{0:2:4:,Cl})-=)}
 \chemrel{<->}
 \chemfig{*6(-=-(\quad\ominus)-(=Cl^{\oplus})-=)}
 \chemrel{<->}
 \chemfig{*6(-(\qquad\ominus)-=-(=Cl^{\oplus})-=)}
 \chemrel{<->}
 \chemfig{*6(=-=-(=Cl^{\oplus})-(\ominus\quad)-)}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please post a minimal example that shows how to draw the halobenzene rings, so we can have something to start with? It will make the job of adding the arrows much easier if we have a starting point already, and since you've got that, it won't be any extra work for you! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please study section 11 *Representig electron movements* of the `chemfig` manual. Here is one possibility which (more or less) exactly uses the mechanism presented there.

The idea is the following: `chemfig`'s formulas are `tikzpicture`s. `chemfig` allows to give the nodes inside the formulas names using its `@{name}` syntax. These nodes can be referred to later in a separate `tikzpicture`. This is what the `\chemmove` macro does: it is a wrapper for a `tikzpicture` with the options `remember picture` and `overlay`. The rest is TikZ…

Both the atoms' nodes and bonds' nodes can be given a custom name. For a atom just add `@{<name>}` right in front of the atom you want to name. For a bond, add `@{<name>}` as first thing in the optional argument of the bond. With a bond you have even more control: the syntax has another option `<pos>`: `@{<name>,<pos>}`. `<pos>` is a number which determines where along the bond the node is positioned, `0` meaning at the start and `1` at the end. Default is `0.5`, i.e., in the middle of the bond.

Below I also used `chemfig`'s scheme mechansim which gives a little bit more control over the arrows between the compounds. Also, `\chemrel` is deprecated and gives a warning in the log:

> Package chemfig Warning: the macro `\chemrel` is deprecated. Please, build schemes with `\schemestart` and inside, use `\arrow`.

Additionally I used `chemmacros` for the formal charge symbols. Instead of trying to position them using some space (`\qquad`) I used shortened invisible bonds. `[,.3,,,draw=none]` sets the length of a bond to 30% (`.3`) and makes them invisible (`draw=none`).

Please also note the `|` in `Cl|^{\fplus}`. The `chemfig` manual says:

> The character “`|`” forces splitting of the atom when it is
>   encountered.

This ensures that the bond and the chlorine are aligned properly.

[image]

You need to compile this twice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}% for formal charge symbols

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \setatomsep{2em}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(-=-@{C1}=[@{db1}](-[@{b1}]@{Cl}\lewis{0:2:4:,Cl})-=)}
    \arrow{<->}
    \chemfig{*6(-@{C2}=[@{db2}]-[@{b2}](-[,.3,,,draw=none]@{ch1}\fscrm)-(=Cl|^{\fplus})-=)}
    \arrow{<->}
    \chemfig{*6(-[@{b3}](-[,.3,,,draw=none]@{ch2}\fscrm)-=-(=Cl|^{\fplus})-@{C3}=[@{db3}])}
    \arrow{<->}
    \chemfig{*6(=-=-(=Cl|^{\fplus})-(-[,.3,,,draw=none]\fscrm)-)}
  \schemestop
  \chemmove[red,->,shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]{
    \draw[shorten <=4pt] (Cl) .. controls +(180:8mm) and +(180:8mm) .. (b1) ;
    \draw (db1) .. controls +(60:8mm) and +(0:8mm) .. (C1) ;
    \draw (ch1) .. controls +(-30:8mm) and +(0:8mm) .. (b2) ;
    \draw (db2) .. controls +(-60:8mm) and +(-90:8mm) .. (C2) ;
    \draw (ch2) .. controls +(-120:8mm) and +(-150:8mm) .. (b3) ;
    \draw (db3) .. controls +(180:4mm) and +(120:4mm) .. (C3) ;
  }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can you please tell what the `[,.3,,,draw=none]` in the 12th, 14th and 16th lines represent?

Comment: @VeerArjunSingh I added something to my answer